# Unwanted Default Values on User Input Window (VB/wpf)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a class called vehicle that has a number of properties but I'll use only one to illustrate tmy problem.  My vehicle class includes this code:`Private clsMileage As Long

```
Public Property Mileage As Long
    Get
        Mileage = clsMileage
    End Get
    Set(value As Long)
        clsMileage = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    clsMileage = vbNull
End Sub`
```

Pretty basic stuff.  My input window has a number of text boxes designed as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:VehicleExpense x:Key="ve" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ve}">

<TextBox
      Name="txtMileage"
      Text="{Binding Path=Mileage}" />
```

When the window opens the digit 0 is in txtMileage textbox.  I do NOT want any value there.  I want the box to be blank so the user can easily enter data.  If I remove Sub New from the vehicle class then the digit 1 appears in the text box.  Where are these numbers coming from?

I tried modifying the binding by setting the mode as follows:
    Value="{Binding Path=Mileage, Mode=OneWayToSource}"

That works to keep the text box blank but when the window opens the textbox has a red border.  But I have NOT added any verification code yet so why does the program think a verification failure has been raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, the value comes from the fact that you're binding the Mileage property which is a `Long` - that means it will have a default value of 0.

In your `Sub New` you are assigning `vbNull` to that Long; `vbNull` happens to be a constant of value 1 (from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbNull`). This is probably not what you meant. The VB.net "null" value is `Nothing`, but that also can't be assigned to a field of type `Long`.

For your second question, the validation error comes from the fact that you can't assign a blank string ("") to the Long value, which causes a Binding error. To fix this you can make your backing field nullable:

```
Private clsMileage as Long?
Public Property Mileage as Long? 
etc.
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx

Comment: I had tried defining the properties as nullable and it didn't solve the problem.  I tried it again and it works as I want it to.  Somehow I must have done something wrong the first time.